# trying to do jquery validate method for regex patterns (number, file type, pin code, etc)

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying to create a method through with I shall be able to validate for all custom pattern.
just have to change the pattern and respective message to display

the current list of things of I am trying to validate is

- indian phone number
- indian pin code
- indian date (dd-mm-yyyy)
- file type for upload
- bank UPI ID

but in the current snippet, just add two

even after adding, valid values, it shows invalid input

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.validator.addMethod('regex', function(value, element, pattern) {
    var re = new RegExp(pattern);
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
  }, 'Invalid Value');

  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      whatsapp_number: {
        required: true,
        regex: "/^\d{10}$/",
      },
      profile_picture: {
        regex: "/\.(gif|jpe?g|svg|png|webp)$/i"
      }
    },
    messages: {
      whatsapp_number: {
        required: "Whatsapp Number Required",
        regex: "Invalid Phone Number",
      },
      profile_picture: {
        regex: "Invalid Profile Picture Format (gif|jpeg|svg|png|webp)",
      },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.9.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Whatsapp Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="whatsapp_number">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profile Picture</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="profile_picture">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Register">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: FYI:  Version 1.9 of jQuery Validate is nearly 7 years old.

Answer (score 0):

This works better - passing an actual regex

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.validator.addMethod('regex', function(value, element, re) {
    console.log(value,this.optional(element),re.test(value))
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
  }, 'Invalid Value');

  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      whatsapp_number: {
        required: true,
        regex: /^\d{10}$/,
      },
      profile_picture: {
        regex: /\.(gif|jpe?g|svg|png|webp)$/i
      }
    },
    messages: {
      whatsapp_number: {
        required: "Whatsapp Number Required",
        regex: "Invalid Phone Number",
      },
      profile_picture: {
        regex: "Invalid Profile Picture Format (gif|jpeg|svg|png|webp)",
      },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.9.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Whatsapp Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="whatsapp_number">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profile Picture</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="profile_picture">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Register">
  </div>
</form>
```